# Поиск по сайту средствами Python

Tags: python, get, requests, модули, документация

у меня вопрос касательно поиска на сайтах где есть форма для ввода слова, по которому идёт поиск на сайте.

Есть ли возможность реализовать на Python такую вещь: Пользователь ввёл в консоль слово и ему приходит текст ссылки на ту страничку (на сайте), что нашёл поисковик того сайта? По сути простенький GET запрос.

Скорее всего нужен модуль, но я не знаю названия и какие вообще есть. Если кто-то знает можете покидать их.

P.s. Умею читать техническую документацию и API документацию (конечно и на English language), так что проблем в изучении какого-либо модуля не возникнет.

Comment: Модуль называется `requests` и он указан в тегах вопроса. Нужен именно он. Можно суть вопроса побольше раскрыть? В чем именно проблема?

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на сайт и, желательно, вашу попытку работы с ним :) А так, откройте инспектор браузера (обычно это F12 или через меню через правую кнопку мышки), там перейдите на вкладку Сети и посмотрите какой http запрос отправляется при поиске на сайте. Этот запрос и нужно повторить

Comment: окей, щас глянем

Answer (score 1):

Несовсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать.
Условно есть сайт, где осуществляется некий поиск?
При этом у вас есть некая программа, куда вы хотите ввести слово для поиска и получить url страницы с результатом поиска?

Если я вас верно понял, то вам нужно посмотреть как осуществляется поиск на сайте. Просто есть сайты, которые формируют url таким образом [http://example.ru/?s=фраза_поиска](http://example.ru/?s=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)
Соответственно, вам даже не придётся обращаться к сайту чтобы сформировать такие урлы.
Если всётаки придётся получать какой-то контент с сайта, то используйте модуль `requests`. С его помощью вы сможете сделать обращение и получить хедеры,контент и т.п.
Если вам нужно будет распарсить полученный контент, используйте `beautifulsoup`

Comment: А есть такие, что делают ajax-запрос и показывают результат внутри страницы, поэтому `url` с параметрами запроса не существует :)

Comment: @gil9red, согласен, поэтому автору нужно посмотреть на поиск и надеяться на лучшее)

Comment: А если используется такой поиск как в API доках по Java: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/index.html

Comment: То что можно использовать? Ведь там не по URL идёт выборка